# Get Param Values from Url String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to obtain parameter values from url string

```
http://example.com/admin/param1/value1/param2/value2
```

I did it already using this:

```
url.split('/param1/')[1].split('/')[0].replace(/\/$/, '');
```

But is there any cleaner alternative ? Something like this ?

```
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
console.log(c);
```

`searchParams` don't give desired results in this case. Pardon if there is already an answer out there. I couldn't find.

Please read the question carefully before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: You could use PURL (https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl) but I guess your single-liner is faster.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it dont work for the string `http://example.com/admin/param1/value1/param2/value2`

Comment: @shreyasdharav your question is missing some information, the parameter you wish to get, is it always at one specific location in the url ? or

Comment: searchParams don't give desired results in this case? Can you elaborate further on that? I think it should @sh

Comment: when I use `url.searchParams.get("param1")` on my string, it outputs undefined. I guess there is no such solution, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the URL always has `/admin/` in it, you could do it like so:

```js
var testUrls = [
    "http://example.com/admin/param1/value1/param2/value2",
    "http://example.com/admin/name/John/age/50/paramWithNoVal",
];

for (var i = 0; i < testUrls.length; i++) {
    var url        = testUrls[i];
    var paramArray = url.split("/admin/")[1].split("/");
    var paramObj   = {};

    for (var x = 0; x < paramArray.length; x++) {
        // i is even - assume this is a param name
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            paramObj[paramArray[x]] = paramArray[x + 1] || null;
        }
    }

    console.log(paramObj);
}
```

**Edit:** as a function:

```js
function getUrlParams(url) {
    var paramArray = url.split("/admin/")[1].split("/");
    var paramObj   = {};

    for (var x = 0; x < paramArray.length; x++) {
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            paramObj[paramArray[x]] = paramArray[x + 1] || null;
        }
    }

    return paramObj;
}

var url    = "http://example.com/admin/param1/value1/param2/value2";
var params = getUrlParams(url);

console.log(params["param1"]);
console.log(params["param2"]);
```